# LLDB output error: use of undeclared type '$__lldb_context'

Tags: swift, xcode, console, lldb

Why sometimes when I try to print in console like this:

```
 po trip.id
```

I get:

```
error: <EXPR>:1:11: error: use of undeclared type '$__lldb_context'
extension $__lldb_context {                            
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<EXPR>:16:5: error: use of unresolved identifier '$__lldb_injected_self'
    $__lldb_injected_self.$__lldb_wrapped_expr_79(     
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

or

```
error: <EXPR>:1:11: error: cannot find type '$__lldb_context' in scope
extension $__lldb_context {
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Any way to fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xcode lldb error: can't print out Swift variable - get "$\_\_lldb\_injected\_self.$\_\_lldb\_wrapped\_expr\_x" instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48245427/xcode-lldb-error-cant-print-out-swift-variable-get-lldb-injected-self)

Answer (score 2):

In order to have expression run as though it were injected into the currently selected frame, we need to construct a context (some kind of class extension, for instance) with an appropriate self parameter, and evaluate the code in your expression in that context.  Apparently, the context in which you are trying to print "trip.id" is one the debugger can't reconstruct.  If you can file a bug with http://bugreporter.apple.com to report this, we can figure out how to support this.

If you aren't using Xcode 8.0, you might try that, a bunch of bugs of this sort were fixed.

lldb has another command, "frame variable" which provides quick access to local variables.  It can't run function calls and the like, but since it is less ambitious it is sometimes more robust.  You might try something like:

```
(lldb) frame variable -O trip.id
```