# Xcode lldb error: can't print out Swift variable - get "$__lldb_injected_self.$__lldb_wrapped_expr_x" instead

Tags: swift, xcode, debugging, lldb

Sometimes, when trying to print out a variable in the debugger, the following error message is displayed:

```
error: warning: <EXPR>:12:9: warning: initialization of variable '$__lldb_error_result' was never used; consider replacing with assignment to '_' or removing it
    var $__lldb_error_result = __lldb_tmp_error
    ~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    _

error: <EXPR>:18:5: error: use of unresolved identifier '$__lldb_injected_self'
    $__lldb_injected_self.$__lldb_wrapped_expr_120(     
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

This is a known `lldb` bug (https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-6156), but perhaps someone knows a workaround that can be used until that bug is fixed?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

As a workaround you can print it in the `lldb` debugger using:

```
frame variable variablename
```

Also possible using shortened syntax for quicker typing

```
fr v variablename
```

Since XCode **10.2** an ever simpler `lldb` syntax is supported:

```
v variable
```

**Update** - new workarounds:

Print stack addresses:

```
v -L variablename
```

`po` like on stack frame variable.property

```
 v -o variablename.property
```

Swift like `p`

```
e unsafeBitCast(address, to: ClassName.self)
```

**Update2** - *new workaround* applicable for Swift classes being wrappers of objc classes.

Example:

```
v response
(HTTPURLResponse) response = 0x0000000283ba7640 {
```

if `v` works^:

```
e -l objc -- (int)[0x0000000283ba7640 statusCode]
(int) $2 = 404
```

**Update 3**
printing Swift arrays (here array of `[Int]`)

```
v -L arrayName
0x00007ff7b753a9a8: ([Int]) arrayName = 1169 values {
0x000060000295e7b0:   [0] = 1
...
```

then

```
e unsafeBitCast(0x00007ff7b753a9a8, to: UnsafeMutablePointer<Array<Int>>.self).pointee[0].bitWidth
```

also possible with `map`

```
e unsafeBitCast(0x00007ff7b753a9a8, to: UnsafeMutablePointer<Array<Int>>.self).pointee.map{ $0.bitWidth }
```

I'd **appreciate reports** what is actually helpful and works. Thanks.

More information on this kind of capabilities can be found here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/lldb-guide/chapters/C5-Examining-The-Call-Stack.html

Comment: Better than nothing, but still quite cumbersome to use... I wonder why this Swift bug (?) isn't fixed for so long 

Comment: This doesn't resolve the problem. It's possible to print the variables in other code bases. Why doesn't it work now? And why does it work with other code bases?