# Unable to use po command in console (debug area)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, debugging, lldb

Suddenly I have started to get this message randomly ( but pretty much often)

> expression produced error: warning:
>   /var/folders/53/0z4yfqt16tvbcn0z7f2385n80000gn/T/expr3-d271e2..swift:3:9:
>   warning: initialization of variable '$__lldb_error_result' was never
>   used; consider replacing with assignment to '_' or removing it
>       var $__lldb_error_result = __lldb_tmp_error
>       ~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       _

when I try to type something like this in console:

```
po myObject
```

So, the console prints only message above, rather than it gives me something useful... How to fix this, and what caused it?

Comment: My bet is you are using Xcode 10.2. Debugging always sucked and is incredible slow, I don't understand why they can't make a debugger that is even close to IntelliJ where everything just works quick. It's so frustrating to debug/program using Xcode

Comment: Hi there! Yeah, I am on 10.2 (10E125) @J.Doe :)

Comment: I think there isn't much we can do, expect wait, wait and more waiting... Hope they can come up with a better Xcode someday

Comment: @J.Doe I hope so. This wasn't the case with previous version of Xcode (at least not for me).

Comment: Debugger console has a new frame variable command alias “v” that is faster than “p” or “po" : i just read it in **What's New in Version 10.2**

Comment: This is a related problem to https://stackoverflow.com/a/48249030/5329717

Answer (score 6, accepted):

lldb has changed in Xcode 10.2. Apple recommends use of 'p' or more recently 'v' to view the values of variables.

from the [Xcode 10.2 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_10_2_release_notes)

> The LLDB debugger has a new command alias, v, for the “frame variable” command to print variables in the current stack frame. Because it bypasses the expression evaluator, v can be a lot faster and should be preferred over p or po. (40066460)

There is also good information on this in the [LLDB Tutorial](https://lldb.llvm.org/tutorial.html) in the section named **Examining Stack Frame State**.

> The frame variable command will also perform "object printing" operations on variables (currently we only support ObjC printing, using the object's "description" method. Turn this on by passing the -o flag to frame variable:

```
(lldb) frame variable -o self 
(SKTGraphicView *) self = 0x0000000100208b40 
<SKTGraphicView: 0x100208b40>
```

Comment: That said, man ... I miss how well gdb and po worked in older versions of Xcode.

Comment: 'v' didn't worked for me once, it always says it can't find anything in the current view frame or something like that. Don't understand why they can't build a working fast debugger.

Comment: @J.Doe it will only work for local variables and arguments (if it's a debug build) (also self being a "hidden" argument here under this reasoning).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using swift.  You can get this sort of error when you upgrade your Xcode but don't completely rebuild all your swift dependencies with the new toolset.  If after you've cleaned all your dependencies (including any Pods or Carthage modules, etc) and rebuilt them all locally, you still get this error, if this is a project you can make available please file a bug either with http://bugs.swift.org or http://bugreporter.apple.com and we'll take a look.

Answer (score -2):

Use debugprint command in place of po command.

Comment: That's not a debugger command