# Xcode 14 po returns error in debug console

Tags: swift, xcode, debugging, xcode14

I have project with Swift and ObjC files inside. After updating to Xcode 14 I have reached problem with PO printing error only during debugging in swift files. In ObjC files PO works great

Tried:

- clean DerivedData
- reinstall Xcode
- download repository from scratch
- p or v command have the same error

Error:

```
   (lldb) po dependencies
    warning: Swift error in scratch context: error: failed to load module 'AppName'
    .
    Shared Swift state for AppName has developed fatal errors and is being discarded.
    REPL definitions and persistent names/types will be lost.
    
    error: expression failed to parse:
    unknown error
```

Comment: take a look on this SO question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55515329/unable-to-use-po-command-in-console-debug-area

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to use po command in console (debug area)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55515329/unable-to-use-po-command-in-console-debug-area)

Comment: This doesn`t work. I get the same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Carthage was the problem of broken debug. When building dependencies on another Mac, the debugger didn`t work. When building on my Mac, the debugger worked
So we decided to transfer all Carthage dependencies to SPM and now debugger works fine :)

Carthage issue link:
https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/issues/924

Comment: Adding to this, you can try to rebuild your carhage libraries again so that your `Cartfile.resolved` file is regenerated. This fixes the debugger for me.

Comment: @GamzRs, yes, but rebuilding fixes this error only for your computer and team will still have the same problem

Comment: currently my team is not open to transfer all Carthage dependencies to SPM (also not my decision to make tbh) so that is why I posted the comment.

Comment: Correct answer for me. Recently Carthage had some issues due to Xcode updates, and I forgot to rebuild my libraries. This worked. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

warning: Swift error in scratch context: error: failed to load module
.
Shared Swift state for coyni V2 QA.app has developed fatal errors and is being discarded.
REPL definitions and persistent names/types will be lost.